# Create pages for authors

Tags: plugin-development, pages, shortcode, author

I have a pretty good question here. I would like to create a hidden page on my wordpress blog for each user as they are registered. I already have most of the code of what needs to be put on the page with a simple shortcode. All I need is something to actually make the page. Here is some of my code.

```
<?php
function added($user_id)
{
global $wpdb;

// Create a page for the user with certain settings
// WHAT DO I PUT HERE!?
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'added' );

function author_page($atts, $content = null)
{
    // Some code here on what to output on the page...
}
add_shortcode( 'author', 'author_page');
?>
```

Well, that's pretty much what I've got with about 350 lines of code in the author_page function and some other stuff that the plugin will do. All I need to do, is in the `// WHAT DO I PUT HERE!?` bit, I need some code that will allow me to create a page, under the subheading authors, make it not seen on the dropdown of that menu page, and then put the shortcode `[author id="1 or whatever it is"]Some description of the Author, or could be left out...[/author]` on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a [custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/custom-post-types/info) named `userinfo`.
- On `'user_register'` call [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) in your filter, and create a new post for the user. Add the user ID as post meta field.
- When the new page is called on the front-end, display the user data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually found this but had to leave and couldn't post my findings. Thanks!